# swscanf return wrong result

Tags: unicode, borland-c++

i use embarcadero Xe7. I found that swscanf returns wrong result.

example

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
 {
 char    *t1=  "  "; 
 wchar_t *t2= L"  "; 
 int     i1, i2;

  i1= -1;
  i1= sscanf (t1, "%d", &i2);   
  if(i1!=EOF)
    printf("sscanf output i1=%d i2=%d\n", i1, i2);   
  else
    printf("sscanf EOF\n");

  i1= swscanf(t2, L"%d", &i2);   
  if(i1!=EOF)
    printf("swscanf output i1=%d i2=%d\n", i1, i2);   
  else
    printf("swscanf EOF\n");

  return 0; 
}
```

the result:

```
sscanf EOF
swscanf output i1=1 i2=0
```

The first result is ok. But the second is wrong.

Comment: Why did you file two separate bug reports in QualityCentral for this bug? The only difference between the two reports is that you categorized #AP-154 as RTL and #AP-155 as IDE+RTL.  Don't do that.  This is not an IDE bug, only an RTL bug, so report #AP-155 needs to be closed as a duplicate of #AP-154. And it is not just an AppMethod bug, it affects RADStudio as well.  And please fix the code formatting in the report(s).

Comment: QualityCentral -> QualityPortal

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. This behaviour of `swscanf()` contradicts the C11 standard:

> **7.29.2.4/3** The swscanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has
>   completed. Otherwise, the swscanf function returns the number of input
>   items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in
>   the event of an early matching failure.

Clearly, here it fails before the first conversion has started.

It also contradicts the [XE7 sscanf/swscanf documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/fr/Sscanf,_swscanf):

> If sscanf attempts to read at end-of-string, it returns EOF.

And again, clearly, here it attempts to read end of string.

There is no bug report for now on EDN.  You should file one.

***Workaround:** process the cases i1==EOF and i1==0 together, as in both cases you can't exploit the content of any variable.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug in XE2, so it has been in the C runtime for a LONG time. This is odd, though, because `sscanf()` and `swscanf()` use the same `_TCHAR`-based implementation internally, so their behavior should be fairly identical. They both are implemented by `_stscanf()` in `$(BDS)\source\cpprtl\Source\io\sscanf.c`, which just calls `_scannert()` in `$(BDS)\source\cpprtl\Source\io\scanner.c`, which does the same parsing logic regardless of whether the input is using `char*` or `wchar_t*`, does take the byte size of `_TCHAR` into account, and handles whitespace the same in both types.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error in XE8 as well.  Looks like Hisham beat me to reporting it to QualityPortal: [AP-154](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/AP-154) and [AP-155](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/AP-155).